# Pass method to decorator with arguments?

Tags: python, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators

Is it possible to pass the decorated method **with** arguments to `__init__` of an decorator?

A simple decorator and usage example

```
class Decorator(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        print args

    def __call__(self, func): # yep the method still have to be callable
        return func

@Decorator
def foo():
    pass
```

---

A decorator without arguments will pass the method as argument

```
$ python foo.py
(<function foo at 0x7fefd7ac1b90>,)
```

When I add arguments to the decorator

```
@Decorator(1, 2, 3)
def foo():
    pass
```

it results in

```
$ python test.py 
(1, 2, 3)
```

As you can see the method is now missing in the passed arguments.

Comment: Try an example with `@Decorator()` and maybe it will click.

Comment: There is a great description [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/674039) (one of the best answers on stack, in my opinion)

Comment: `@Decorator` basically means `foo = Decorator(foo)`. Therefore `@Decorator(1, 2, 3)` means `foo = Decorator(1, 2, 3)(foo)`; `Decorator(1, 2, 3)` should *return a decorator*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we pass arguments to a decorator we need to create an additional function that accepts those arguments and then returns the actual decorator:

```
def decorator_creator(*args):
    class Decorator(object):
        def __init__(self, func):
            print args
            print func
            self.func = func
        def __call__(self):
            return self.func()
    return Decorator

@decorator_creator(1, 2, 3)
def foo():
    pass
```

Output:

```
(1, 2, 3)
<function foo at 0x0000000002EB9EB8>
```

Comment: Probably worth noting that for the vast majority of cases, implementing a decorator as a class, even if it needs arguments, is overkill, and arguably less clear code; an outter closure usually suffices, and makes for more readable code.  Or at least define the decorator object outside the decorator function scope, then initialize and return an instance when the decorator is called.

Comment: Just a minor observation, won't this code create a `Decorator` class every time the decorator is applied?

Comment: @PauloBu That is required, because we're using a free variable `args` in our class here. If we move the class outside of the function then the class won't be able to access `args`.

Comment: Unless you make `args` the arguments to the class' `__init__` and return an instance, which seems to make more sense here...

Comment: @Lucas I accidentally removed the `__call__` method instead of fixing it.

Comment: @SilasRay If I return an instance from `decorator_creator` then it would call the `__call__` method of that instance during function creation time itself.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative that doesn't need inner classes:

```
class decorator(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        # This creates the decorator
        self.args = args

    def __call__(self, func):
        # This applies the decorator
        self.func = func
        return self.call

    def call(self, *moreargs):
        # And this happens when the original function is called
        print self.args, self.func, moreargs
        return self.func()

@decorator(1, 2, 3)
def foo():
    pass
```

I've also made use of `functools.partial(self.method, func)` for decorators.  Sometimes useful.